# Random Crash with CA::Layer::set_position

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, crash-reports, cclayer

I have a crashing bug in my app.

It happens in the same place, but not all the time. I haven't found the problem.

Here are two crash logs:

> ```
>     Incident Identifier: EB73AE61-00FB-4282-8F1D-B8ECEC19E02D
> CrashReporter Key:   6f005b28e796b18f3ab2687bb364b2be1eb137cd
> Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
> Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/BF2F1016-8C00-40A3-BB75-0933F53741F0/*******.app/******
> Version:         ??? (???)
> Code Type:       ARM (Native)
> Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
> Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Last Exception Backtrace:
> 0   CoreFoundation                    0x312d13e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x38fc295e objc_exception_throw + 26
> 2   CoreFoundation                    0x312d1302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
> 3   QuartzCore                        0x32e8e106 CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) + 206
> 4   QuartzCore                        0x32e8e02e -[CALayer setPosition:] + 46
> 5   QuartzCore                        0x32e8dfc2 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 554
> 6   UIKit                             0x330e1bd2 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 230
> 7   UIKit                             0x330e18fc -[UIImageView _setViewGeometry:forMetric:] + 180
> 8   UIKit                             0x330e183a -[UIImageView setFrame:] + 42
> 9   etapes                            0x0006de1c 0x5c000 + 73244
> 10  UIKit                             0x33203136 -[UIScrollView _endPanWithEvent:] + 3694
> 11  UIKit                             0x3321c520 -[UIScrollView handlePan:] + 120
> 12  UIKit                             0x331fdc5c _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 124
> 13  UIKit                             0x331c539c -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 388
> 14  UIKit                             0x333b215e ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 + 42
> 15  UIKit                             0x330e987e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 214
> 16  UIKit                             0x330e82c8 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1160
> 17  UIKit                             0x330f31e2 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 762
> 18  UIKit                             0x330f2dae -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 86
> 19  UIKit                             0x330e08dc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
> 20  UIKit                             0x330e01ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
> 21  GraphicsServices                  0x34df75f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586
> 22  GraphicsServices                  0x34df7222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
> 23  CoreFoundation                    0x312a63e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
> 24  CoreFoundation                    0x312a6386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
> 25  CoreFoundation                    0x312a520a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
> 26  CoreFoundation                    0x31218238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
> 27  CoreFoundation                    0x312180c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
> 28  GraphicsServices                  0x34df6336 GSEventRunModal + 70
> 29  UIKit                             0x331342b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
> 30  etapes                            0x0005e15e 0x5c000 + 8542
> 31  etapes                            0x0005e114 0x5c000 + 8468
> ```

//////////////////////////// SECOND CRASH LOG ///////////////////////////////////

> ```
> Incident Identifier: 4FE03135-D442-4CEA-B230-8322647262EE
> CrashReporter Key:   6f005b28e796b18f3ab2687bb364b2be1eb137cd
> Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
> Process:         etapes [2916]
> Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/BF2F1016-8C00-40A3-BB75-0933F53741F0/******.app/****
> Version:         ??? (???)
> Code Type:       ARM (Native)
> Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
> Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000064
> Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> Thread 0 Crashed:
> 0   UIKit                             0x33df7b06 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) actionForLayer:forKey:] + 138
> 1   QuartzCore                        0x33ba7786 -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 70
> 2   QuartzCore                        0x33ba7732 _ZL12actionForKeyP7CALayerPN2CA11TransactionEP8NSString + 54
> 3   QuartzCore                        0x33ba7626 CA::Layer::begin_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*&) + 126
> 4   QuartzCore                        0x33ba2322 CA::Layer::setter(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 178
> 5   QuartzCore                        0x33bce782 -[CALayer setBackgroundColor:] + 30
> 6   UIKit                             0x33e0ef50 -[UIView(Internal) _setBackgroundCGColor:withSystemColorName:] + 1016
> 7   etapes                            0x000fc8d2 0xdd000 + 129234
> 8   etapes                            0x000f8c6a 0xdd000 + 113770
> 9   CoreFoundation                    0x31fe9ad0 __invoking___ + 64
> 10  CoreFoundation                    0x31f4128a -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
> 11  Foundation                        0x328eaf60 -[NSInvocationOperation main] + 108
> 12  Foundation                        0x32874a84 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 836
> 13  Foundation                        0x328ecfe2 __block_global_6 + 98
> 14  libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a0f1790 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
> 15  libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a0f15d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
> 16  libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a0f4e40 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 224
> 17  CoreFoundation                    0x31fba1ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
> 18  CoreFoundation                    0x31f2d238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
> 19  CoreFoundation                    0x31f2d0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
> 20  GraphicsServices                  0x35b0b336 GSEventRunModal + 70
> 21  UIKit                             0x33e492b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
> 22  etapes                            0x000df15e 0xdd000 + 8542
> 23  etapes                            0x000df114 0xdd000 + 8468
> ```

If you want more details, I'm available!

after research, here is the code that is the problem :

```
self.imageviewFondArticle.frame = CGRectMake((-((_imageviewFondArticle.frame.size.height*imageRatio)-320)/2),0, _imageviewFondArticle.frame.size.height*imageRatio, _imageviewFondArticle.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: These are two rather different stack traces, so if they have the same underlying cause, it's probably a heap corruption issue.  Run it under the Zombies instrument and see if you find any.

Comment: I've testing the Zombie Instrument but the app does not crash with the simulator.
After 10 min to testing I have not Zombie objects.

Comment: The problem would be related AFNetworking ... in progress

Comment: after research, here is the code that is the problem : self.imageviewFondArticle.frame = CGRectMake((-((_imageviewFondArticle.frame.size.height*imageRatio)-320)/2),0, _imageviewFondArticle.frame.size.height*imageRatio, _imageviewFondArticle.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, CALayer's "frame" is a "computed property" according to [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/frame). You may want to be setting the bounds, anchorPoint or position properties. (In contrast, UIView's frame can be set and animated.)

Second, I came to this post 'cos I encountered such a crash as well. It happened when I was setting a CALayer's position property. It turned out that the exception thrown was for an invalid position - one of the coordinates was NaN. I found this by wrapping the "layer.position = pos" in a @try-@catch block. Fixing the root cause of the invalid position solved the problem for me. Based on this, I would guess that you have an invalid "imageRatio" value.

Comment: I don't know why but the integer "imageRation" return NAN value after moments.

This problem are only in the iOS 6.1.